# Is there a way to trigger sidebar by clicking things in contextual add-in?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

The main logic of the application is implemented in the `sidebar` part of the app.

I thought there might be some Outlook API or `Office.js` method for it but didn't manage to find one.

What I need is a possibility to parse entities in an email, show some basic information in a contextual add-in with some buttons on it.
Then what I want to do is to show detailed information about some entity's part in a sidebar by clicking a corresponding button in a contextual add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming by sidebar you mean TaskPane add-ins.
No, all web-based add-ins get activated by user action (either clicking on add-in button / add-in link (in case of contextual add-ins))
It is not possible to launch an add-in from another add-in.
But you can show a dialog, if you want more real estate to show the content.